# Build an SAML IDP provider in React and NodeJS stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, saml-2.0, openedx, samlify

We are an early stage SaaS company with UI in React and services in Node JS. We have been asked by one of our customers to become an SAML identity provider. It would be an IDP initiated SSO and we would be the IDP. openEDX would be the Service Provider. We have tried to look for literature and sample code in React or Node but haven't found a clear documentation anywhere. Could someone please point to a literature or a library that we should refer to?

We have tried samlify.js and tried to create an endpoint in our react app. We have written a provider xml. We are however stuck at how to generate response xml and how to send it to the service provider. Would it be a response redirect or how else?

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to find a solution?
My task is similar. I also stumbled upon samlify, they somewhat started a guide on implementing IdP here: https://github.com/tngan/samlify/discussions/447

I also found [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) is another alternative for diy IdP.

Comment: Hi, I think what you need is keycloak or OneLogin. Once you configure anyone of them you can easily attach them as IDP in edX.

Comment: @ZamanAfzal Did you read the post? "we would be the IDP. openEDX would be the SP."

Comment: @AKX I hope this will help. 
https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/configuration/tpa/tpa_SAML_SP.html